# How to Update an Offline Centos 8 Repository

Tags: linux, centos

Ok, so I work in a lab with isolated networks from the Internet. I have a Centos 8 VM on this network that I use for a repository. I got an updated extras repo on a connected system and zipped it up and transferred it into the Centos 8 repo. What is the proper way of updating the extras repo with this repo file? Meaning, is there a way to use the createrepo command with a certain switch that will update the extras repo directory with the new or upgraded packages? Or do I just delete the current extras directory and its subfolders and then run the createrepo command on this new file like a new repo? Just keep in mind its an isolated network with no Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Running `createrepo` should just work if you placed new files into an already existing repo.

Comment: and it will determine old files that are not needed anymore and get rid of them?

Comment: I once had the same issue and just deleted the old files manually. Also, with today's storage it's not even an issue - just leave the files be, unless you absolutely need to free up space. Probably it could be automated but I didn't find an easy solution and gave up.

Comment: createrepo just updates the repository metadata with all the files it sees in the directory.  It doesn't know what are new and what need to be removed.